# Place contents of last command line output into clipboard

Tags: bash, unix, command-line, terminal

I want to be able to run a command in my Terminal, and then quickly be able to copy the contents of the output into my clipboard without leaving my keyboard. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

No terminal emulator I know of let save the output from commands in the clipboard just using the keyboard.

An useful tool for the purpose could be [`xclip`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xclip/). You can use it like this:

- paste with middle mouse button:

  ```
  $ some_command | xclip
  ```
- paste with <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>

  ```
  $ some_command | xclip -selection clipboard
  ```

Comment: fos OS X use `pbcopy` instead of `xclip`

Comment: Anyway to do this after the command has already been run though? Not sure if that's important to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

See this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177700/copy-current-command-at-bash-prompt-to-clipboard

It explains how to use the bind command for copying the last command into the clipboard.

Comment: He doesn't want the command, he wants the contents of the output.

Comment: The question seems to have been edited for a different purpose than what I originally tried to answer.